# How to store and retrieve image from room database

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I am building a blog application that allows a user to add picture for the blog post. I am currently storing the data as URI string but the issue I have is that the image only shows when I first add it, if I refresh the page or relaunch the application the image will not show, just a blank space with no image.

### Database Entity

```
@Entity
class PostEntity(
    var title: String,
    var body: String,
    var image: String? = null,
    var date: String?

): Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0

    var likes:Int? = 0



}
```

### Capturing Images from gallery and camera and converting to URI string

```
    private fun openCamera(){
        try{
            val CAMERA_REQUEST = 200
            val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST)
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please try again: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

// function to be called in onActivityResult
    private fun loadImage(requestCode: Int, imageView: ImageView, context: Context, data: Intent?){
        if(requestCode == 200){
            try{

                val image = data!!.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap


                imageView.setImageBitmap(image)
                imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                imageUriLoader = getImageUriFromBitmap(context, image)
            }
            catch (e:Exception){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please try againt: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }

        else if(requestCode == 201){
            try{
                val imageUri = data!!.data
                imageUriLoader = imageUri
                Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(imageView)

                imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)

            }
            catch (e:Exception){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please try again: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

I have seen some post about using blob, most of them are not clear and the fact that blob only allows image size limit of 1MB makes want a better option.
Please kindly help with a better to save and restore images.

Comment: I suggest to convert it to [Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57626674/10182897) and store in room or you can store it's path in db

Comment: Images should not be stored in the DB. Instead, they must be stored as files on the device, and their corresponding path must be stored in the DB

Comment: @AtishAgrawal Kindly assist with how to do that

Comment: @Ashish Kindly help with that please.

Comment: if your going with base 64 i have provided link how to convert and take the base64 string and store inside the db.

Comment: You should upload the images to your server or aws s3, and use the resulting url with any photo loading libraries like glide or picasso for better user experience.

Comment: @SonuSanjeev i don't that's good solution. Might he is trying to make offline application.

Comment: @Ashish If he is building a blog application, it should at some point upload the blog post to a server right?

Answer (score 0):

In your database you should have a field of type String (or the equivalent VARCHAR etc.) that serves as image path inside a directory of your choice, so for example

[image]

Then you can add whatever fields you need, for example in your case you would need a userID that serves as a foreign key to the user logged in.
So as soon as the user loads an image you save the file to the path you desire and then save that same path inside the db so that next time the user loggs in you look up his image path and then load it on the web page.